# Wouldn't shooting Perkins in a diamond formation cause one of the shooters to be hit?

Tags: analysis, john-wick

Towards the end of John Wick (2014), Perkins is summoned by Winston.  For whatever poor decision she made, she walked into the center of 4 ominous looking characters.  Winston let her know her Continental transgression was unforgivable and the four shooters each shot Perkins.

Wouldn't one of the shooters be hit with one of the bullets?  I suppose hollow tips would solve that issue, but in any case, this seems a bad design for a planned execution.

Comment: At the end, Perkins seems that she knew what will happen to her and there's no escaping from that. We can see no opposition from her, just like she let her fate to do things, she accepted her fate. and I don't think that Winston will get untrained stupid guys for such a delicate task. They are professionals and that means this isn't the forst time. So it have zero to teeny tiny chance to one get hit by another

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As with many other aspects of the John Wick films, there's a sense of symbolism and style in some of the scenes.

There's absolutely no reasonable reason for an execution squad to arrange themselves in this manner in order to execute their business.

It's pure theatre.  It's there to look good and bring the figurative into the physical and tell the story.

> We know you, and you have been judged.  We have you physically and figuratively surrounded.  There is no escape.  You will emphatically die, and you will be accepting of that judgement and sentence.

Comment: Additionally, we don't have a perspective on all of them. It's possible to surround someone an not have a colleague be in direct line of fire. Ricochets, altered trajectory, etc could all factor but of course this is the movies